# Keep the mouse pointer in primary monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, mouse

**Problem:**
I have a main monitor that is not touch-sensitive and a secondary one that is touch-sensitive. When I touch the secondary monitor the mouse pointer goes to that monitor and I don't want that.

Version of Windows 10: Version 21H2 (compilacion de SO 19044.2728)

Second monitor: AZMIOR Portable Touchscreen Monitor 15.6 ’’

**I tried:**
There is an option in the Actual Multiple Monitors program that is to lock the mouse on the monitor, it half fulfills its function, which is that when touching the touch screen the pointer does not go to the other screen but it moves to the edge of the actual monitor.

**I expect:**
Only when I move the mouse pointer do I want it to go to that monitor, not when I touch it, when I touch it I want the mouse to stay on the main screen?

Any software or tweaks on Windows 10 for this?

Comment: Touching the screen is the same as a click, so disabling it will disable click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need the touch to keep working. I was seeing that the tablet function can achieve this, but it is disabled when connecting the second monitor.
Maybe other recommendation?

Comment: You could try with Dual Monitor Tools, DisplayFusion or a similar app. They have options to make cursor stick to one monitor. Not sure if touch still works though.

Comment: Not sure why you readded AutoHotKey tag - the question has nothing to do with it, the answer does, but the tags are for **question**.

Comment: Tag issue resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for those interested, autohotkey is necessary.

```
SetTimer, MousePos, 1000

MousePos:
MouseGetPos, x, y
return

~LButton::
   TimeL := A_TickCount
Return

~LButton Up::
   Time := A_TickCount - TimeL
   xp := x + Abs(x)+1 + (1920 - Abs(x))

   If (Time < 20){
     if (x < 0){
    MouseMove, %xp%, %y%
    } else {
     MouseMove, %x%, %y%
    }
   }
   ;~ Else {
      ;~ ToolTip MOUSE %Time%
      ;~ sleep, 300
      ;~ ToolTip
   ;~ }

Return
```